# Using Selenium ChromeDriver to get page DOM, calculate speed

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

I am trying to use Selenium and ChromeDriver to get the complete DOM of a page as quickly as possible. When my important Ajax requests are finished I inject a class into the dom and use a WebDriverWait to wait for that class before continuing.

When I test the responses from the api (the ajax calls) they are very consistent, I have also removed any requests to adservers, or anything outside the website and api. I have inspected the requests from server logs and wireshark and again, they are very consistent.

The time it takes for ChromeDriver  to get the full dom varies wildly. Below are the arguments and switches I am using. I am getting anything from 700ms - 4 seconds to get the full dom for the same page. Are there switches I am using here that are impeding ChromeDriver? What should I use if I simply want the DOM, nothing else? How can I optmise for speed?

Using Selenium.WebDriver.3.5.0 and Chrome 60.

```
        chromeOptions.AddArguments("headless", "disable-gpu", "renderer");
        chromeOptions.AddArgument("disable-translate");
        chromeOptions.AddArgument("no-default-browser-check");
        chromeOptions.AddArgument("site-per-process");
        chromeOptions.AddArgument("disable-3d-apis");
        chromeOptions.AddArgument("disable-background-mode");
        chromeOptions.AddArgument("site-per-process");
        chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.managed_default_content_settings.images", 2);
        chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("credentials_enable_service", false);
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you disable images and css loading?

Comment: I disabled images, how do I disable css loading? I was just looking for a switch for that and was about to comment!

Comment: I blocked CSS loading on the server serving the web app, so it's not returned to Chrome now. It helped a bit. I still think My command line switches are all over the place to be honest

Comment: Would you consider an Answer in Java?

Comment: Yes, I have nothing against Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My use case was to use chrome webdriver to generate a full dom to be sent to crawlers. It was to be a replacement fro prerender.io.

I have seen some other developers want to try this too.

My advice is to not do this. It's isn't designed for it and there is nothing you can do to make the responses more reliable in my experience.

If yu are using angular, use universal (https://universal.angular.io/) we tested this and it works great.

For other JS frameworks, https://prerender.io is still an option.

Thanks.